# Crontab, Meaning of */50 in Minutes Field

Tags: cron

OK, I see a crontab line like:

```
*/50 * * * 1-6 command
```

Now, if my research is correct, something like */2 makes sense (minutes divided by 2, or every 2 minutes) and */5 makes sense (every 5 minutes).

In fact, the command happens to run at 50 minutes after the hour. Which makes sense as 60/50 is 0 remainder 50. But if that is the desired effect, why not just put 50 instead of */50?

Am I missing something, or did the original programmer just get too clever?

I'd like to just change it to 50, which I believe was the original intent, but I don't want to change anything without understanding the effects.

Answer (score 0):

`cron` is stateless and does not remember when was the last time it executed a task.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#cite_ref-jenkins_15-0):

> Note that frequencies in general cannot be expressed; only step values
>   which evenly divide their range express accurate frequencies (for
>   minutes and seconds, that's /2, /3, /4, /5, /6, /10, /12, /15, /20 and
>   /30 because 60 is evenly divisible by those numbers; for hours, that's
>   /2, /3, /4, /6, /8 and /12); all other possible "steps" and all other
>   fields yield inconsistent "short" periods at the end of the time-unit
>   before it "resets" to the next minute, second, or day; for example,
>   entering */5 for the day field sometimes executes after 1, 2, or 3
>   days, depending on the month and leap year; this is because cron is
>   stateless (it does not remember the time of the last execution nor
>   count the difference between it and now, required for accurate
>   frequency counting—instead, cron is a mere pattern-matcher).

Comment: So, essentially, */50 and 50 end up meaning the same?